# Can I specify BASE to apply to a specific scope?

Tags: html

`<BASE>` by default applies to every link in the page.  Is it possible to specify for it to apply to only a certain element, eg all the links in one <table> or a certain CSS class?

I am migrating a website to a new hosting company. The new location has more expensive and less storage. I want to continue to keep the large quantity of audio files in the old web site.

Previously, the old web site refers to the recordings as href='/audio/xxx.mp3'.  Now from the new web site it would be href='http://theoldwebsite/audio/xxx.mp3'.  I would hate to add the long string 'http://theoldwebsite' to every single link in the audio listing pages.

Comment: no, it is impossible with `base`